# Error message"...No such file or directory" when trying to set up project to inteact with Git

Tags: github, version-control, repository, rstudio, git-bash

Using the following programs and interfaces:

- R-4.2.2 for Windows
- RStudio Desktop: Open Source Edition (AGPL v3)
- Git Bash
- GitHub

I am currently in the early stages of a tech program learning Data Analytics.
On my PC, working within RStudio, I've created a project that is currently not under version control. I am trying to get it set up to interact with Git.

When I type in my command (`cd ~/dir/name/of/path/to/file`) for it to move around and navigate to the directory containing my files, I keep getting this error message:

```
bash: cd: /c/Users/Administrator.STEPHHOWERTON/dir/name/of/path/to/file: No such file or directory"
```

I've tried creating different pathways. My original directory pathway was:

```
 cd: /c/Users/Administrator.STEPHHOWERTON/RStudio Projects/Temporary_add_to_version_control
```

Then I tried to simplify by creating a easier path like the example in my module:

```
c/Desktop/Temporary_add_to_version_control
```

No luck with either.
I went ahead to try initialize the directory to as a Git repository and also tried to add files, but of course it said the directory was empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to switch to command line (simple CMD, no bash required), after having installed [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

Go to the root folder of your repository (not path/to/file, but path/to/root/folder/of/repository), where your project is.

You can then create a repository

```
git init .
git add .
git config --global user.name "your name"
git config --global user.email "your@email.com"
git commit -m "Import project"
```

If you need to create a GitHub repository and push your project, you can, from that same folder, after [installing GitHub CLI `gh`](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation), use [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login) (with a [classic PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token#creating-a-personal-access-token-classic), scope [`repo`](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes)):

```
gh auth login --with-token < echo ghp_...
```

Then [`gh repo create`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_repo_create):

```
gh repo create my-project --public --source=. --push
```

You can reopen RStudio from there, and check everything is working.